# How can I save CLLocation better?

Tags: ios, core-location, cllocation, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I am trying to save my CLLocation location for future use in my app. I have come up with the following:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Locations.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];

[data setValue:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:location] forKey:@"LocationList"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: (NSData *)[data objectForKey:@"LocationList"]]];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
```

When I run my app, the compiler returns

```
-[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better and standard way to save CLLocation data?

Comment: Do you wan't specifically to use NSKeyedArchiver? Or would using CoreData make sense? What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

You've lost track of what your methods are actually returning, which is a risk when you embed multiple message calls inside each other.

You stored a CLLocation, so this is returning a CLLocationObject:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: (NSData *)[data objectForKey:@"LocationList"]]
```

You code is treating it as though it was returning an array:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:... // Your returned CLLocation here.
```

That is why the array was NULL. As to how to store CLLocation data, the encoding approach is correct. (See [this answer for a clear reference to storing CLLocations as NSData objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27592395/dictionary-becomes-nil-when-trying-to-pass-back-cllocation-object-to-ios-app-ext/27848301#27848301).)