# Dictionary becomes nil when trying to pass back CLLocation object to iOS app extension

Tags: swift, dictionary, cllocation, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to pass a stored `CLLocation` object from my iOS app back to an extension (in that case: an Apple Watch extension).

For that, I'm using the recommended `openParentApplication(userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!, NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Bool` function from the `WKInterfaceController` class in the extension code. I'm successfully receiving the request in my iOS app through the application delegate's `application(application: UIApplication!, handleWatchKitExtensionRequest userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!, reply: (([NSObject : AnyObject]!) -> Void)!)` function.

Now, I'm trying to pass data back to the app extension using this code:

```
    var results = [NSObject: AnyObject]()
    if let loc = getLastKnownLocation() {
        results["hasLoc"] = "yes"
        results["locStr"] = "\(loc)"
        results["results"] = loc // at this point, loc is actually a valid CLLocation object
    }
    reply(results)
```

All this code is executed in the iOS app's context and everything is working fine. However, when the `reply` function gets called in the extension's context, the dictionary ultimately becomes `nil`.

```
    InterfaceController.openParentApplication(parentValues, reply: {(values, error) -> Void in
        NSLog("\(values) (err: \(error))") // echoed back to the console: "nil (err: nil)"
    })
```

I realised that the faulty line is this one:

```
                results["results"] = loc
```

When this line is commented, the extension successfully gets a dictionary filled with the two first items as strings (`"hasLoc"` and `"locStr"`):

```
[locStr: Optional(<+37.33756323,-122.04115699> +/- 10.00m (speed 5.00 mps / course 272.00) @ 21/12/2014 19:20:05 heure normale d’Europe centrale), hasLoc: yes] (err: nil)
```

So it seems like inserting a `CLLocation` object in my dictionary makes it all fail and become `nil`, but I can't understand why. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: per @matt's request, here's the code for `getLastKnownLocation()`:

```
class func getLastKnownLocation() -> CLLocation? {
    return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(NSUserDefaults(suiteName: AppHelper.appGroupName)!.dataForKey("UserLastLocation")!) as CLLocation?
}
```

Comment: @matt, see my question update.

Comment: I think that's just because `locStr` is a string representation of the `loc` variable, which as you know know, is an Optional `CLLocation?`.

Comment: OK now I understand your point. But I just changed the `as CLLocation?` to `as CLLocation` and the function signature to `CLLocation` instead of `CLLocation?`. It doesn't solve the problem, but now `locStr` does not show up as `"Optional"` anymore.

Comment: Yes I had to refactor it as `let loc = getLastKnownLocation()`, but the `CLLocation` still won't make it to the extension app, only the value types seem to be transferred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read in the docs: "The contents of the dictionary must be serializable to a property list file." But a CLLocation is not serializable in this way. Presumably you must wrap it up (again) in an NSData before you stick it into the dictionary to be passed across the barrier.

Comment: Third time lucky?... Try this and see what happens.

Comment: Yeah, you're on the right way! Now I manage to get bytes back to the extension, but I'm currently unable to convert it back to a `CLLocation` object. I'm using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` but it won't convert back...

Comment: Never mind... I was casting to `CLLocation` all the dictionary items even the `String`s... Now it works, it's just not very convenient to cast to and back from `NSData`, but at least, it works! Thanks @matt!

Comment: Sorry for all the wrong answers; Watch Kit is new. I learned along with you! Thanks for letting me do so.

Comment: Don't be sorry, you helped me a lot. I'm coming from ObjC and I'm learning both WatchKit and Swift at the same time so your help is very welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

[The Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:) states, "The contents of the dictionary must be serializable to a property list file." A CLLocation is not serializable in this way. In order to include it in the NSDictionary that is returned in this context, you need to wrap it up as an NSData object. This is straightforward. CLLocation supports NSSecureCoding, and you use an NSKeyedArchiver like this:

```
CLLocation *myLocationToStore = ...; // (a CLLocation object)
NSData *locationData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myLocationToStore];
```

This can then be added to the NSDictionary, passed to the app extension, and then decoded at the other end just as simply with NSKeyedUnarchiver:

```
CLLocation *myStoredLocation = (CLLocation *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:locationData];
```

The [Swift equivalent functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archivedDataWithRootObject:) are:

```
class func archivedDataWithRootObject(_ rootObject: AnyObject) -> NSData]
class func unarchiveObjectWithData(_ data: NSData) -> AnyObject?
```